# Generic jquery function for cascading dropdownlists (asp.net mvc)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a medical appointment system and I'm using a jquery function to filter the items in my cascading dropdownlists. Is there a way of writing a 'generic' to handle all the dropdownlists instead of writing the same thing several times?

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ddlIl').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Users/GetIlce",
                    data: { Id: $('#ddlIl').val() },
                    datatype: "json",
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var ilce = "<select id='ddlIlce'>";
                        ilce = ilce + '<option value="">--Seçin--</option>';
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            ilce = ilce + '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                        }
                        ilce = ilce + '</select>';
                        $('#ddlIlce').html(ilce);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

I have the following dropdownlists: State, City, Department, Hospital, and Doctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap the AJAX call in a function to serve all dropdownlists in view, probably this code below apply for them:

```
/*
 *  @param url = URL to fetch data (i.e. controller action method 
 *               returning IEnumerable<SelectListItem> or SelectList)
 *  @param source = source dropdownlist name
 *  @param target = target dropdownlist name
 */
function cascadeDropDownList(url, source, target) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { Id: $('#' + source).val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            // remove previous option contents first
            $('#' + target + ' option').each(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            // add new option contents
            var options = '<option value="">--Seçin--</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                options += '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
            }
            $('#' + target).html(options);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage in `change` event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlIl').change(function () {
        var url = '/Users/GetIlce'; // recommended: '@Url.Action("GetIlce", "Users")'
        var source = $(this).attr('id');
        cascadeDropDownList(url, source, 'ddlIlce');
    });
});
```

NB: The function above assumes target dropdownlist has already created in view page and you just want to insert option element values without recreating `select` element. If you want to create new target dropdownlist instead, modify the function like below:

```
/*
 *  @param url = URL to fetch data (i.e. controller action method 
 *               returning IEnumerable<SelectListItem> or SelectList)
 *  @param source = source dropdownlist name
 *  @param target = target element (e.g. div)
 *  @param ddlName = target dropdownlist name
 */
function cascadeDropDownList(url, source, target, ddlName) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: { Id: $('#' + source).val() },
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            var ddl = "<select id='" + ddlName + "'>";
            ddl += '<option value="">--Seçin--</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                ddl += '<option value=' + data[i].Value + '>' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
            }
            ddl += '</select>';
            $('#' + target).html(ddl);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlIl').change(function () {
        var url = '/Users/GetIlce'; // recommended: '@Url.Action("GetIlce", "Users")'
        var source = $(this).attr('id');
        var target = $('#targetdiv').attr('id');
        cascadeDropDownList(url, source, target, 'ddlIlce');
    });
});
```

Working example: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VEDt0l)

Comment: Thanks that exactly what I needed